# What does this warning of gcc mean?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, malloc

Could anyone tell me what does this warning mean?

```
s_sort.c: In function 'main':
s_sort.c:15:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function
'malloc' [enabled by default]
A[i].name = malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
```

I am trying to execute the following code. The platform is GCC 4.8.1 on Windows x64(TDM-GCC).
The problem is as far as I see in accessing structure members.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 3
#define MAXCHAR 100

int main(){
    struct STUDENT
    {
        int studentID;
        char* name;
        char grade;
    } A[MAX];
    int i;

    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        A[i].name = malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
    }
    for (i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&(A[i].studentID));
        scanf("%s",A[i].name);
        scanf("%c",&(A[i].grade));
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",A[i].studentID);
        printf("%s ",A[i].name);
        printf("%c ",A[i].grade);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        free(A[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>.`

Comment: +1 for not casting the return value of `malloc()` and therefore catching the error!

Comment: For your information, this particular issue was what created the whole [do not cast the result of malloc debate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Did you compile this as C90 or C99? You might get different warnings/errors if you do. Older, crappier C90 compilers might not even give a warning, but leave the bug hidden in your program.

Answer (score 4):

It means the compiler was unable to find a declaration of your `malloc`. Therefore it generates a default `int malloc(...)` declaration for you. Just `include <stdlib.h>`.